# How to check file exists via Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to clone a repo and test it after is done via bash script. I have written my test code based on [Bash Shell: Check File Exists or Not](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-test-existence-of-file-in-bash/).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "*** TRY TO INIT INFER ***"

# Clone Infer
INFER_GIT_PATH="https://github.com/facebook/infer.git"
echo "> Try to Clone Infer from ${INFER_GIT_PATH}"
git clone ${INFER_GIT_PATH}

INFER_PATH="/infer/infer/bin/infer"
[ -e ${INFER_PATH} ] && echo "Infer downloaded successfully" || echo "Something went wrong :("
```

Although repo can be downloaded successfully and `/infer/infer/bin/infer.sh` exists, I'm always getting `Something went wrong :(` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to this (use a relative path):

```
INFER_PATH="./infer/infer/bin/infer"
[ -e ${INFER_PATH} ] && echo "Infer downloaded successfully" || echo "Something went wrong :("
```

and it should work.

Comment: That line was my mistake, I just updated my code. Thanks for pointing out but I still have same output :(

Comment: so the name of your file is infer or infer.sh?

Comment: I updated my comment. You have to use a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a file exist, you can use `-f` flag:

```
[ -f /infer/infer/bin/infer ] && echo "Infer downloaded successfully" || echo "Something went wrong :("
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting `Something went wrong :(`